# Why do c++ programmers use != instead of <

Tags: c++

In c++ primer, pg 95 the author says that c++ programmers tend to use != in preference of < when writing loops.

```
for (vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i != 10; ++i) is preferred instead of 
for (vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
```

I read the same thing in accelerated c++. Can someone explain the rationale behind this

Comment: Whoever writes the above code must be executed. See http://blogs.csoonline.com/node/151

Comment: @ybungalobill: good article, bad conclusions :)

Comment: @Kos: just joking :) and of course it's not so critical in a for loop.

Comment: If the author of the book is to be believed, then what is the correct comparison operator when incrementing like: i+=2 or i+=7 etc....? another stupid generalization of the type defined as the following: "Those who can, do; those who can't, teach or author crappy c++ books" :D

Comment: @Zenikoder: stupid generalization indeed. Maybe you should've read the book and you'd have understood both the context of the "rule" and the rationale behind it. Instead, of course, it is oh so much easier to take it out of context and spew some generic crap about how clueless some of the world's best c++ programmers must be. I don't suppose you noticed the word "preference" in the question? No one suggested using != when it yields in correct code. Just that when both will do the job, C++ programmers have reason to prefer !=

Comment: @Zenikoder:    Crappy C++ books? C++ primer is written by Stanley Lippman, Barbara Moo and Accelerated c++ by Andrew Koenig. They are some of the most respected persons in c++.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

When using some kinds of STL iterators (those that aren't random access), you *must* use `!=`:

```
for (map<int,int>::iterator i = a.begin(); i != a.end(); ++i) ...
```

However, I don't see any reason to prefer `!=` for well-ordered scalar types as in your example. I would usually prefer `<` for scalar types and `!=` for all iterator types.

Comment: Well I guess the reason would be so that all your for loops read the same

Comment: Correction: when using STL iterators, except random-access ones, you must use !=. So in case of vector<int>, < is fine.

Comment: You do not have to use `!=` for all STL iterators. Random access iterators will work just as well with `<`.

Comment: Also, you should use `!=` unless you must use `<`. See C++ Coding Standards, item 67. Using `<` needlessly is unnecessarily ungeneric and a premature pessimisation.

Comment: @ltjax - Where are these hypothetical coding standards you mention?  Personally, I prefer programming defensively to making sure I can randomly change the type of a loop variable.  I suppose if I were using `auto` that might change.

Comment: @Itjax: I've clarified my preference statement, it was needlessly misleading after my previous edit.

Comment: @Omnifarious - they are not hypothetical, but a book by Herb Sutter and Andrei Alexandrescu

Comment: @ltjax - Looks like a book worth reading, though I will likely disagree some with parts of it.  :-)  But there are so many C++ coding standards out there, you should be specific when referring to one.

Comment: Also note that just because `!=` is correct for simple iteration doesn't make it correct for other types of loop. In particular, it's a bad idea to use it when you can move multiple steps in the loop – it's unwise to do that unless you've got an iterator that supports an ordering relation – or if you're working with floating point numbers. (Using floats as iteration variables is a thing for experts only, and that's because the experts tend to know to not do it…)

Answer (score 32):

It's a habit for generic programming; for example, you can easiely use `<` with indices, but you cannot use that with all iterator types. A list iterator cannot efficiently implement `<` - however, `!=` can be implemented for even the simplest of iterator types. Therefore, it is a good habit to always use the most generic comparison - it makes your code more resilient to change.

Answer (score 10):

Think of the case when one have to increment by lets say 3 instead of 1.

```
for (vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i != 10; i+=3)
```

This will run forever since it will skip 10 and go to 12 instead and increment forever.

```
for (vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < 10; i+=3)
```

This will work fine in this case too. So != is not always a good choice.

Comment: Actually the first one will stop on a binary computer, that's because 3 is a generator of the ℤ/2^nℤ group.

Comment: Err.. this is true, but it really doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: This is just a counter-argument for the usage of !=

Comment: It's not really a counter argument: using `!=` protects the code against long range changes - i.e. when you change the type of the container/range you're using. Using `<` only protects you against changes of the actual iteration step, which have to happen in that very same line.

Answer (score 8):

Because, in general, not all iterators support the "<" operation. See [the manual](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/) for operation supported by each iterator type. Only random access iterators (of which, simple pointers are a subset) support inequality comparisons (< and >) between iterators

Answer (score 7):

The requirement of being "relationally comparable" is a much stronger one than the requirement of being "equally comparable". When it comes to iterating over containers, the possibility to perform relational comparison between iterators or generic indices (like `<`, `>`, `<=` etc.) is strongly associated with random-access containers, while the equality comparisons are more universally applicable (and often the only ones available when working with sequential access containers).

In general, it is a good practice to make you code as generic as possible, i.e. you should never rely on stronger requirements when weaker requirements are perfectly sufficient. In other words, if you can implement your algorithm by using equality comparisons only, it is better to do it that way, without bringing in any relational comparisons. It is possible that way you will make your algorithm more usable with a wider range of underlying data structures (containers).

Of course if you don't care about this kind of genericity or simply don't need it, you can just ignore these considerations and use either approach.

Comment: +1 for rationalising on a mathematical basis, particularly for _"you should never rely on stronger requirements when weaker requirements are perfectly sufficient"_.

Answer (score 7):

If you write `!=`, then you can reverse the loop iteration with minimal change.

Suppose you first write:

```
for ( int i = m; i != n ; i++ )
```

Later you reverse it:

```
for ( int i = n ; i != m ; i-- )
```

Not so appealing, but still it requires **less** analysis than "<" and ">".

Comment: However, the first loop will cover the range [m, n) while the second will cover (m, n].

Comment: @itjax: Nice catch. I didn't notice that. thanks for pointing out it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe those who preffer this is because they got used to checking for null, etc... so preffer use the same != in everything.

```
if(x != null) { ... }

for(int i=0; i != 10; i++) { ... }
```

so for those everyting tends to be !=  or ==

read **!=**  as  **DIFFERENT/NOT EQUAL**,
following the same principle as **==**  is **EQUAL**,