# for loop in c++, any difference between these two style?

Tags: c++

Style one: `for (int i=0;i<10000;++i){...}`

Style two: `for (int i=0;i!=10000;++i){...}`

Let's say what happens in the `{}` will not affect the value of `i`, what is the difference between these two style? since I have checked with the compiler they all get the same results.

Comment: The first one is "safer" because it will keep working for increments of more than 1 (for example if i went from 9999 to 10 002)

Comment: Just think about the behaviour of both loops if the block would just contain `i = 10001;` and nothing else.

Comment: actully I'm more concerned about the efficiency part, which one is faster while we got to have lots of iterative times?

Comment: @memmove != vs < is likely to make little if no difference at all in the performance of your program. You're better off optimizing the body of the loop. But of course you should profile the program first before blindly optimizing things.

Comment: @memove: that may be what you're interested in, but it is not what you're asking.

Comment: I vaguely remember a very similar (or duplicate) question not so long ago. But I can't find it (nor the right search terms)...

Comment: Something similar here http://stackoverflow.com/q/16309905/4807777

Comment: It's quite a popular question

look at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/71006

Comment: @Borgleader The second one is “safer” since it works with non-random-access iterators.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I dont see any iterators in that question =/

Comment: @Borgleader I’m a fan of syntactic consistency when using a fixed syntactic form (here: “iterating over a range”). Other people recognise that this is desirable, which is why we have range-based `for` loops in modern C++ (and range-based `for` loops can of course be used to iterate over numeric ranges, see e.g. https://github.com/klmr/cpp11-range/ — The benefit from this far outweighs the theoretical risk of skipping over the upper bound by accidentally increasing the loop variable by more than 1.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Oh this is neat! You should add a section about loops to your [C++ ppt thing](http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp/#1) ;)

Comment: @Borgleader Hmm. I agree that the slides could use an update but unfortunately I’m not teaching C++ at the moment so I can’t really justify the effort to my employer. ;-)

Comment: Also see [Why do C++ programmers use != instead of <](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531429/why-do-c-programmers-use-instead-of)

Answer (score 4):

Given this particular question, there is no difference. However, in general, the first style is preferred because it is slightly safer.

Think about what happens if `i` becomes something like 10,001? In the first style, the loop will terminate. Whereas in the second style, you get an infinite loop.

If you stick to the first style, you'll also be able to increase `i` by anything that isn't a factor of 10000 and still guarantee termination of the loop.

Comment: You mean 'potential endless loop' because once you overflow `int`, you may hit 10000 again. And if the loop deals with memory one will probably get a segmentation fault before reaching the overflow.

Answer (score 0):

No difference in this case. The commonly used '<' sigh is just for safty purpose. In case you work with `float` instead of `int` or the value of `i` is modified inside the loop so that it may skip the value against which it is checked.
As default choice, prefer '<' over '!=' unless '!=' is really required like in pointers comparison.

Comment: I'd be suspicious of a for loop that used a float as an iterating value.

Comment: Me too but it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

if you also manipulate `i` inside the loop, there are chances that `i` may not equal `10000` in second style at any point of time and it might become infinite loop.

Where as in first style even if `i`'s value is incremented inside loop for any condition, the loop will certainly terminate at some point of time.

Edit: Even if `i`'s value will not be modified inside the loop, and if you assume these are just two ways of doing the same thing, As a programmer you must choose the first style as it has meaning, readability and slightly safer for obvious reasons.